# MacBook Air issue

Tags: macbook-pro, power

I have been experiencing difficulty with my MacBook Air and decided again to try and investigate/repair

In short, it does not turn on whatsoever. I have taken apart the unit and the moisture indicators show nothing - so so damage from moisture I assume

I have left it on charge overnight and it is still on orange.

When I put the charging cable in, it goes orange immediately, then green, and then orange

SMC reset does not work.

Any tips? Should I order a new battery??

Thanks in advance
James

Comment: Take it to an Apple Store to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Before doing anything else i would check that it isn’t the charger. The cable doesn’t age well and might be failing.  Any chance you can borrow a different one somewhere?